# My tablet's screen has gone black

Tags: samsung, screen

My tablet screen has gone black. I have shone a flashlight into the screen and I can just about make out the display and when I move the toggle up and down to adjust the brightness it does nothing it just stays the same. I've switched it off and on a few times but it has done nothing, I am not using any custom roms. Also I haven't broken it of dropped it in any way, I have only had it since Christmas.

I'm using Samsung Note 10.1, 2014 edition.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that the LCD backlight has died. This would indicate a hardware fault. But before we jump to conclusions,

- Make sure you don't have a screen filter like (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor) active.
- Factory reset it and see if the problem persists.